# Joomla 2.5 shows add/edit form for article/category incompletely

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-article

When I click on add new article, Joomla shows the page incompletely.

It doesn't even show the form itself completely.

[image]

Even now that I have enabled the debug mode, it doesn't show anything. I think that something `die()`s the process of outputting the page to the browser.

Please note that I haven't had a **bad** joomla installation. It was working very well a bit little ago.

I haven't also changed a deep core setting. I think that I have only changed jcomment setting that doesn't look related to the problem.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Looks like a problem with Installation of joomla or try changing browser.

Comment: @Irfan Eror reporting is set to `development` in Global configuration, but doesn't still show anything

Comment: @om39a it doesn't matter at all. The screenshot is taken with Firefox but it's exactly the same with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in this file `root/administrator/components/com_content/content.php`

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

If no error comes check for die or exit statement with any of the editor which  has search functionality.If this also does not work rename the com_content of administrator and upload  the fresh one.

let me know if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Putting those codes resulted in the following errors: 
`Warning: require_once(__DIR__/functions.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/helpgig/public_html/dmf/plugins/system/nnframework/helpers/assignments.php on line 16` ++++ and ++++
`Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/helpgig/public_html/dmf/plugins/system/nnframework/helpers/assignments.php on line 16`. I'll now try to resolve these problems.

Comment: @smhnaji:good to know that it worked.dont forget to remove the code after problem is resolved.

Comment: But why didn't joomla show the error while I had enabled error reporting in global configuration? Why did that have to be stated exactly in its proper file?

Comment: @smhnaji:I have not seen the core but what I think is joomla only does this error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);But in php.ini "display_errors" is not set.So it gives error but not displays it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable that plugin.

Did you just add it or update?
If the file is there check the ownership.

Comment: Thank you for your try to solve my problem, but it has been resolved right now :)